# Connecting multiple loads in self-balancing parallel

Tags: led-strip, impedance-matching, constant-current, load, balancing

I have three (or 'n', where n=3 at the moment) large LED panels that I want to run in parallel.

As we know (or should have known before the 'royal we' actually tried it!), just wiring them together in parallel leads to them being at very different brightnesses because even tiny differences in resistance will lead to relatively larger differences in current flow through each path (duh).

I have in the back of my head that there is a very simple discrete (like just resistors and caps, basically) self-balancing circuit that solves this problem. But I keep getting a Wheatstone bridge when I try to draw it out.

I can't find what I'm thinking of through simple internet search. The search terms "load" combined in any way with "balancing" ends up with computer load balancers of an infinite variety.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a link to the datasheet for the LED panels.

Comment: Can you put a driver in each panel?

Comment: A series connection self balances for current. Passive solutions for parallel, like large series resistors balance well, but are inefficient. Small resistors don't balance well. You need an active solution, semiconductors as well as resistors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> even tiny differences in resistance will lead to relatively larger differences in current flow through each path

Not quite.  It is differences in the forward voltage (Vf) of each individual LED that add up to a significant difference in overall voltage drop from one panel to another.  The panel with the lowest total Vf hogs current from the ones with higher Vf, even if the difference is only a few tenths of a volt.

The solution is actually *more* resistance.  If you add a resistor in series with each panel, so that now there are three resistor-LED-panel circuits connected to the voltage source in parallel, you can size the resistor such that the voltage drop across it is larger than the voltage differences among the panels.  This decreases efficiency and brightness, but you can compensate for the brightness by increasing the driving voltage.  The ballast resistors will work to even out the current through the panels, and it is the current that determines an LEDs brightness.